# Spotfire - Is there a way to 'drill up' instead of drill-down?

Tags: spotfire

Spotfire has the ability to drill down via 'create details visualization' that allows you to click on an element in a graph and view just that data inside another graph.

My question is about doing the opposite.  I have a scatter plot where each dot is an individual row of data (with name, dollar amount, etc columns).  I want to click on a dot (which is an individual row of data), and in a second visualization see every row of data that shares the name value with that individual row of data.

Essentially this is a 'drill-up' from one row of data.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not so easy like details visualization, but surely you can do that.

Best way I could think of:

- As you've already created your scatter plot, let's build on that:
- duplicate your data table: add data tables - add - from current visualization - select your original table
- link the two tables on [name] column: edit - data table - relations - manage relations - new - select original and copied data tables and [name column for both]
- create your "drill up" visualization based on the copied table
- open properties of this new visualization and go to "data" and in "limit data using markings" check the colour you use in your original visualization

I know it sounds complicated, but in practice it's easier and works:)

Comment: Thanks for the response Mate!  I was able to get this to work.